# Performance inserts statement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-poi, query-performance

I have application that reads from excel sheet , number of records more than 25000 records. I calculated time to insert records to database is
15 minutes,currently using MySQL which may change to db2 later on.

I insert all statement direct to MySQL, the time taken is 14 minutes.

Is it normal ? Are there any ways to increase performance? or code enhancement  ?

```
/**
     * insert records excel sheeet in tables 
     * @param dbConnection
     * @throws Exception
     */
    void insertRecords(Connection dbConnection,Sheet sheet,int sizeColumns ,String tableName) throws Exception {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {


            Sheet datatypeSheet =sheet;
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            StringBuilder sbInsert = new StringBuilder( 1024 );

            //skip first row 
            iterator.next();

            //iterator for rows excel sheet
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                sbInsert.setLength(0);

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();

                sbInsert.append("insert into "+tableName.trim().replaceAll(" ","_")+" values(");

                int currentCellLenght=0;


                //iterator for cell rows
                for(int cn=0; cn<sizeColumns; cn++) {


                    Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cn, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    currentCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String cellValue;

                    cellValue=currentCell.getStringCellValue();

                    sbInsert.append("'"+cellValue.replaceAll("\'", "")+"'");


                    currentCellLenght++;


                    if(currentCellLenght==sizeColumns) {
                        break;

                    }

                    //add insert rows 
                    if(currentCellLenght!=sizeColumns) {
                        sbInsert.append(",");
                    }


                }

                sbInsert.append(")");

                preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sbInsert.toString());
                preparedStatement.execute();


            }

        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());

        }finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            dbConnection.close();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query to db is taking 14 mins not your `for` loop? Try debugging it further.

Comment: what is size of xlsx saved as csv?

Answer (score 2):

When you naively hit an InnoDB table in MySQL with a series of insert statements, it automatically commits each statement before it takes the next one. That takes lots of extra time.

You can work around this by doing your inserts in multiple-row chunks.

One way is to chunk your inserts with transactions. At the beginning of your operation, do `Connection.setAutoCommit(false);`. Then, every few hundred rows do `Connection.commit();`. Don't forget to do a last `Connection.commit();` after all your rows are processed. And, if you'll go on to use the same connection for other things, do `Connection.setAutoCommit(true);`.

Another way is to issue multi-row inserts.   They look something like this.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES
   (val1, val2, val3, val4),
   (val5, val6, val7, val8),
    ...
   (val9, vala, valb, valc);
```

Each set of values in parentheses is a single row.  You can fit ten or even fifty rows in each of these insert statements. This itself is a way of chunking your inserts, because each multirow insert uses just one transaction.

Another way to speed this up (probably an inferior way). Use a MyISAM table rather than InnoDB. MyISAM doesn't have transactions, so it doesn't have the overhead. But transactions are good when you use tables in production.

Chunking makes a **big** difference to bulk insertion performance problems like yours.

Comment: When using JDBC, one should **not** use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` as statements. Instead, you should disable auto-commit mode using `Connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and explicitly commit using `Connection.commit()` (or rollback using `Connection.rollback()`), failure to do so may lead to undefined behavior of the driver.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @MarkRotteveel. I edited my answer.

Comment: I never saw multi row insert before.

Comment: One of my reasons to participate in Stack Overflow is that I learn something new every day.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for your answer, i set `dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);` at the beginning insertRecords method and end method `dbConnection.commit();` i don't divide to hundred the time take for this the result as below :                              Start >>Sun Feb 25 01:17:14 IST 2018
End  >>Sun Feb 25 01:18:21 IST 2018                                                                                            total time 66 s

Answer (score 0):

1st with JAVA the 2nd run is always faster because of loads and other initialization.  Keep up the good work.

**Code Review.**

Your evaluating the same thing twice.
You could shave some time here with an else statement.

IRL your iterating for the sizeColumns no need to check for it.  1st if statement not needed.

IRL Do the first column then start the iterations now just put a comma before each value and close out the statement at the end. 2nd if statement is no longer needed.

> ```
> if(currentCellLenght==sizeColumns) {
>                         break;
>
>                   }
>
>                     //add insert rows 
>                     if(currentCellLenght!=sizeColumns) {
>                         sbInsert.append(",");
>                     }
> ```

Comment: Can you explain more i can't understand ?

Comment: You don't need either of those if statements.  The first one is automatic because thats your for statement.  The second one IRL you would do the first column before the for statement processing columns hence every column  in the for statement gets a comma before the value so the sbInsert.append(",") is done on every row.  No if statement needed.